# PHP Warning/Error on Wordpress Site

Tags: wordpress, php

I'm getting this warning message on a Wordpress I have just setup:

http://wptest.paddingtonterraces.com.au/

**Warning:** call_user_func_array() [function.call-user-func-array]: First argument is expected to be a valid callback, 'gllr_add_script' was given in **/home/paddingt/public_html/wptest/wp-includes/plugin.php** on line **403**

Anyone know how to sort this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deactive your plugins and theme and activate them one by one so you will find out which component causes the problem or which plugin does the function comes from.

Answer (score 0):

It's looking for a function named `gllr_add_script`... does that function exist?

Comment: Like @Dean says, its looking for a function that isn't there. Search your theme for 'gllr_add_script', maybe start in your theme's functions.php file. That often is the scene of the crime.

Comment: @dean - It appears to be a function related to the gallery plugin that I'm using. There doesn't seem to be any problems with the gallery itself, all appears to be working fine. When I deactivate the plugin I don't get the warning.